Mobile Publisher Has Offline capabilities?
I came across Salesforce Mobile App Plus where user can do edit,read,create,delete while offline and when back online salesforce automatically syncs it.
Read through many documents and still not clear if Offline capabilities using features like Briefcase Builder, Priming are available for Mobile Publisher?
I am in the process to get mobile publisher license hence not able to actually test it. If someone can confirm or give me any update on this it would really be helpful.
Does Salesforce mobile publisher support offline capabilities?
